# Is it possible to trigger the didRecieveLocalNotifcation method if the app is closed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In app delegate, I have written some code in the `didRecieveLocalNotification` Method which firstly determines which local notification was triggered, and then generates a UIAlert once the app re opens after clicking the notification banner.

If my app is closed, the `local notification` is still received, and clicking on it does re open the app from its terminated state, however the code inside of the `didRecieveLocalNotification` method is not triggering at all. I can't even get a NSLog to work.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can get this information in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but only if user taps the local notification.

> When the system delivers a local notification, several things can happen, depending on the application state and the type of notification. If the application is not frontmost and visible, the system displays the alert message, badges the application, and plays a sound—whatever is specified in the notification. If the notification is an alert and the user taps the action button (or, if the device is locked, drags open the action slider), the application is launched. In the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method the application delegate can obtain the UILocalNotification object from the passed-in options dictionary by using the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey key. The delegate can inspect the properties of the notification and, if the notification includes custom data in its userInfo dictionary, it can access that data and process it accordingly. On the other hand, if the local notification only badges the application icon, and the user in response launches the application, the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method is invoked, but no UILocalNotification object is included in the options dictionary.
>
> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is called if the application delegate implements it. The UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the userInfo dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When you app is neither running nor in the background, your notification is received in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your app delegate.

You can use the below code to access the notification object.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];  
            if (localNotif) {       
                // Show Alert Here
            }
    }
```

Comment: I used the following code inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it worked!

Comment: UILocalNotification *notification =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];